# Fixed columns in Power BI matrix pivot table

Tags: powerbi

I need to create a pivot table visualization in which one of the columns should be independent from the pivot. I try to explain better: I have this setting:

ROWS:
OBJECT_ID

COLUMNS:
DATE (year/quarter/month/day)

VALUES:
SOLD QUANTITY

Now I need to add a column next to OBJECT_ID in which I can see something that is independent from the date.

Is it possibile? And how?
(Nesting a pivot table in a simple table should be fine but I don't know if is it possible or not)

Thank you

Comment: I don't think it is a feasible question, since excel doesn't have such function also as you can only use the excel column beside pivot table for independent information only.

Comment: This is PowerBI, but anyway I don't care the position of the independent column. If it is the first or (better) the last, is the same

Comment: As adding an extra column, this is only possible as an extra level but that is not what you want. I do believe you only talk about visualization. Another option is to add the data as concatenated (creating a new column with OBJECT_ID & the extra data..

Comment: @Aldert Yes, in fact I tried with concatenation but in this way I can't order by those values for example

Comment: Than I would go with a second visual. So keep the concatenation and have a second visual where you can sort, filter etc. Hour matrix will go along...